# Draw a history of roads taken that follows the roads. Google Map API ANDROID

Tags: android, google-maps, location, draw, google-polyline

[This is my current map and what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fLai.png)
We see in blue the current lines drawn, and in red those expected.
I want the user's trips to follow the road and not get out. I have no clue on how to proceed.
And feel free to give some advice on the user's locations data storage in database to make a "
history road taken". Thanks!

```
     mMap = googleMap;
     ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
coordList.add(new LatLng(XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX));
        coordList.add(new LatLng(XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX));
        coordList.add(new LatLng(XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX));
        coordList.add(new LatLng(XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX));
        coordList.add(new LatLng(XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX));
        coordList.add(new LatLng(XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX));
        coordList.add(new LatLng(XXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX));
        Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(coordList)
                .width(10)
                .color(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: You need [Snap on roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap?hl=en). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47329243/6950238) question. If your path didn't  have enough points use approach like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49135356/6950238).

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Thanks! I will implement this method.